# Understanding "repositories" tags

Tags: android, android-studio, tags

I am confused why same `repositories` tags are required in multiple places in an Android project. Why don't we have all repositories under one tag, and the compiler searches everything from there.

My particular case is:

I created a library module and added it in a project. In my library gradle file, I have:

```
implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
```

for which I added `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in `repositories` tag in the library's gradle file. I want EasyImage in the library only, not in the project. But it wont compile until I added this same `jetpack.io` in Project's `app/build.gradle` file. Why do we need to do this?

I want to distrubute my library and I don't want the users to add things that are already added in my library and are not required by their project.

Comment: I've changed my answer, let me know if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
If you put jitpack repository url in your Project level build.gradle instead of app level build.gradle it will work for both. When you upload your library to JitPack, it automatically 'builds' your library for you but in your case your library is being built locally so it needs the repository url in each build file to build them separately. However you should keep the repository url in your library because eventually you will be distributing it and JitPack won't be able to build your library module if you have the url in your project build.gradle file instead of repository.

**Previous Answer:**
From what I understand: 
You are using EasyImage in your library, and when you add the ibrary to your project, you want to use the same EasyImage library that you loaded in your library instead of adding it to your project.

if you load your library using 'implementation' like this:

```
implementation 'com.github.you:yourlibrary'
```

you will not be able to access dependencies that 'yourlibrary' uses. But if you load it using 'api'

```
api 'com.github.you:yourlibrary'
```

Now you can access EasyImage from this library instead of adding it again.

This was added in Gradle 3.0 and it works the same way as 'compile' keyword used to work(which is deprecated now). You should checkout [this article](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) for detailed explanation.

**Why this behavior?**:
By using imepentation,
if any implementation in EasyImage is changed, Gradle just needs to recompile EasyImage and Your library as any other class which does not import your library directly cannot use any implementation of it.

But if you use api to load library, If any change is implemented inside EasyImage, gradle needs to recompile EasyImage, Your library and all other modules which import your library as any other module might use implementation of EasyImage (like your app).

Comment: u r telling me what i already know. Again, in my question, why do i need to add JitPack in my project module, when my project doesn't implement EasyImage. My library implements EasyImage, and I have added JitPack to the library gradle already.

Comment: @M. Usman Khan ok so what you are trying to say is that you imported EasyImage to your library so now you want to use it in your app from your library instead of loading it again?

Comment: No. I need EasyImage only in my library. But without adding JitPack in "repositories" to project gradle AND library gradle, it wont compile.

Comment: No brother. My library uses EasyImage library, which is hosted at jitpack

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan If you are not publishing through JitPack, that means you are adding your library locally. If you put jitpack repository in your **Project level** build.gradle instead of **app level** build.gradle it will work for both.

When you upload your library to JitPack, it automatically 'builds' your library for you but in your case your library is being built locally so it needs the repository url.

Comment: Library is added locally atm, but again "I need EasyImage ONLY WITHIN MY LIBRARY", so y do i need to add it to Project level gradle?

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan aare you certain there is no other library in your project that uses jitpack?

Comment: Yes. When I remove the jitpack from App module (or from the library gradle file), i get the same compilation error. i.e. "EasyImage could not be found.. searched here ... " . I m only using EasyImage in my library.

Comment: @M.Usman Khan load the library as an AAR file instead of adding the code to your app, that should solve the issue. The reason is probably that when you build your app your library is not built separately from your project

Comment: Also make sure that you've added your library to settings.gradle file

Comment: I tried to do the AAR file. But then I ran into this issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54548134/1397821 . Now I'll try to deploy my lib to some host.